# What should be the most logical and appropriate 9th term in this sequence?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Consider this sequence

> 3, 5, 10, 20, 39

What is the pattern? I initially thought it might be a pattern of *2-1, *2,*2,*2-1 (a group of *2-1,*2,*2 repeating itself), but don't think this is a valid pattern.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: Mam i just have this nothing else no author or anything for attribution but still i got the point , if i ever will be able to find anything to attribute i will surely give it

Comment: There is [a unique match](http://oeis.org/A057755) on OEIS. According to that sequence, the 9th term is $617$.

Comment: @Orion Pax  Your sequence is not  complete. The complete sequence derives from the relation $2^{2^n}+1$ where $n$ takes values from zero to infinity. So the correct sequence is  1,1,2,3,5,10,20,39,78,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the 9th Fermat number, $2^{2^8}+1$, which has 78 digits. So the 9th number in your sequence is $78$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be

> 593

Explanation - Series can be thought as

> $2^1 + 1$
>
>  $2^2 + 1$
>
>  $2^3 + 2$
>
>  $2^4 + 4$
>
>  $2^5 + 7$

We see that

> All numbers are $2^x$ and an additional component which is like fibonacci but with last 3 numbers (1, 1, 1+1=2, 2+1+1=4, 4+2+1=7)

So we can continue this

> $2^6 + (7+4+2) = 2^6 + 13$
>
>  $2^7 + (13+7+4) = 2^7 + 24$
>
>  $2^8 + (24+13+7) = 2^8 + 44$
>
>  $2^9 + (44+24+13) = 2^9 + 81 = 593$

Comment: See Tribonacci numbers, http://oeis.org/A000073